# How do I overwrite an existing zip file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have made the following utility method to compress files in my solution. I was under the impression that when ever it produced a .zip archive that has the same name as an existing one it would overwrite it. This does not seem to be case though and an exception is thrown stating that the file already exists.

```
public static void CompressFile(string zipName, string filePath, string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zipName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error("Exception Caught: {0}", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Is there a boolean overwrite param somewhere that I'm missing or do I need to write a check that will delete a pre-existing archive of the same name?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchivemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  "Only creating new archive entries is permitted"

Comment: and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485716%28v=vs.110%29.aspx : `When you set the mode parameter to Create, the archive is opened with FileMode.CreateNew as the file mode value. If the archive already exists, an IOException is thrown.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the Remarks in the documentation for [ZipFile.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485716(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When you set the mode parameter to Create, the archive is opened with FileMode.CreateNew as the file mode value. If the archive already exists, an IOException is thrown.
>   When you set the mode parameter to Update, the archive is opened with FileMode.OpenOrCreate as the file mode value. If the archive exists, it is opened. The existing entries can be modified and new entries can be created. If the archive does not exist, a new archive is created; however, creating a zip archive in Update mode is not as efficient as creating it in Create mode.

So the problem is down to the underlying File handling. When you use `Create` as the ZipArchiveMode, the API is implicitly attempting to create a file without handling its already existing. In your case, the `Update` ZipArchiveMode is probably more appropriate. The [FileMode enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) goes into more detail about what each value mentioned above allows and requires.

That being said, if you are looking to *replace* an existing archive rather than alter its contents, you will need to [check for its existence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [delete it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) if it exists before opening the archive in `Create` mode.

Comment: I figured that would end up being the case, was just curious if there was some overload boolean param I was missing some where. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: bool zipExists = File.Exists("C:\file.zip"); if(zipExists) File.Delete("C:\file.zip");

Answer (score 4):

As @Dan J was mentioning in his answer, all you have to do is to check for existence of the file and delete the same if it is not necessary and then create it. A working code snippet is given below.

```
private void ZipTheFolder() {
    try {
        if (File.Exists(ZipPath)) {
            File.Delete(ZipPath);
        }
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(FolderFromZipLocation, ZipPath);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new CustomConfigurationException($ "Error when zip: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Simple -- delete the zip before you write to it. If it didn't exist before -- no harm.

For safety's sake you could also first create the new one, then move it over the old one with a force command.

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

ZipArchive.Open adds new files to an existing zip archive. Always make sure to read the docs to make sure you are using the right method!

Nathan